# Adding button to each row in react (flux) fixed data table

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add button to each row in fixed data table, but I don't know how. My current code:

```
var Details = React.createClass({    

    getInitialState() {
            return {
              rows: usersStore.getUsersList(),
              filteredRows: null,
              filterBy: null,
            };
          },    

           componentWillMount() {
            this._filterRowsBy(this.state.filterBy);
          },

          _rowGetter(rowIndex) {
            return this.state.filteredRows[rowIndex];
          },

          _filterRowsBy(filterBy) {
            var rows = this.state.rows.slice();        
            var filteredRows = filterBy ? rows.filter(function(row){
              return row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            }) : rows;

            this.setState({
              filteredRows,
              filterBy,
            });
          },

          _onFilterChange(e) {
            this._filterRowsBy(e.target.value);
          },

    render: function () {   

        return (

            <div>
                <label>filter by <input onChange={this._onFilterChange} /></label>
                <Table
                 height={200}      
                  rowHeight={30}
                  rowGetter={this._rowGetter}
                  rowsCount={this.state.filteredRows.length}
                  width={450}
                  maxHeight={450}
                  headerHeight={40}>
                  <Column
                    label="Name"
                    width={270}
                    dataKey="name"
                  />
                  <Column
                    label="Age"
                    width={100}
                    dataKey="age"
                  />
                  <Column
                    label="Qualification"
                    width={120}
                    dataKey="Qualification"
                  />
                  <Column label="Edit"
                    width={120}>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.update}>Update</button>
                  </Column>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }    
})
```

While using this code it showing datakey is mandatory and if I remove column tags and adding only button in table also its not accepting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample code of adding buttons to each row in react fixed data table

```
    var Table = FixedDataTable.Table;
var Column = FixedDataTable.Column;

var EmpTable = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      rows: [
        {title: "Ramu", rank: "1", year: "2000"},
        {title: "Harsha", rank: "2", year: "1999"},
        {title: "Hussain", rank: "3", year: "1998"},
        {title: "Vamsi", rank: "4", year: "1997"},
        {title: "Mahesh", rank: "5", year: "1996"},
        {title: "Nitesh", rank: "6", year: "1995"},
        {title: "Subbu", rank: "7", year: "1994"},
        {title: "Kamal", rank: "8", year: "1993"},
        {title: "Kishore", rank: "9", year: "1992"},
        {title: "Venu", rank: "10", year: "1991"},
        {title: "Bhasi", rank: "11", year: "1990"},
        {title: "Suresh", rank: "12", year: "1989"},
        {title: "Ramesh", rank: "13", year: "1988"},
        {title: "Narendra", rank: "14", year: "1987"},
        {title: "Anil", rank: "15", year: "1986"}
      ]
    };
  },


  _displayDataForRow(rowData, rowIndex){      

    alert(rowIndex);
    alert(JSON.stringify(rowData));

  },

  _renderButton(cellData, cellDataKey, rowData, rowIndex){

    return <button style={{width: '80%'}} onClick={this._displayDataForRow.bind(null, rowData, rowIndex)}>click</button>;

  },

  _rowGetter(rowIndex) {
    return this.state.rows[rowIndex];
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table
          rowHeight={30}                  
          rowGetter={this._rowGetter}             
          rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}          
          width={500}
          maxHeight={200}
          headerHeight={30}>

          <Column
           label="Name"
           width={200}
           dataKey="title"
          />
          <Column
           label="Rank"
           width={100}
           dataKey="rank"
          />
          <Column
           label="Year"
           width={100}
           dataKey="year"
          />
          <Column
           label="Click"
           width={80}                      
           cellRenderer= {this._renderButton}                 
          />
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

EmpTable = React.createFactory(EmpTable);

React.render(EmpTable(), document.body);
```

Comment: Thanq for your support

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons = [];
SomeButtonsProps.forEach(function(props) {
    var button = <button> props.whatever </button>;
    buttons.push(button);
});
```

Then
   return(
       
           {buttons}
       );

This should work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a v6 migration of APIs that deprecated constructs such as the CellRenderer.

https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/v6-migration.html

But the new solution is pretty cool.

That page hints at how to write own custom renderers that
can inject own HTML elements in list columns.